# jquery conflicts on my Magento checkout page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, magento, autocomplete

I am using Magento 1.7 version. On my checkout page I have added Autocomplete code with jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui.js. If I use jQuery.noConflict(); below the jquery-1.10.2.js, the Autocomplete works perfectly however I am not able to see the Menubar. And if I use jQuery.noConflict(true); it is showing menu however, I am not able to select the Autocomplete City Value by keybord (I am able to select the City Value by Mouse).

What could be the issue? 
What is missing?
Where am I going wrong?
What/Where should I place jQuery.noConflict(true)/jQuery.noConflict()?

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

noConflict(true) will set $ as the jQuery variable, and you can **no longer use jQuery** to call functions like jQuery('#someelement).focus() because jQuery will be undefined.

If you code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict(true) 
</script>
```

as the first line of the html, and then replace every jQuery with $ (which is good practice anyways) then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I placed <script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict(true) 
</script> at start of my html page and replaced the jQuery with $ however, I am facing the same issue. Though jQuery.noConflict(true) is at the top of the html I have to add this line below the jquery-1.10.2.js. otherwise autocomplete stops functioning.